# Check a string for consecutive repeated characters

Tags: java, string, character

It is asked in an interview to write the code in Java to display the string which doesn't have consecutive repeated characters.

E.g.: Google, Apple, Amazon;
It should display "Amazon"

I wrote code to find continues repeating char. Is there any algorithm or efficient way to find it?

Comment: If you already wrote the code, try posting it over at [codereview.se] if you want people to look at it.

Comment: What does "continues repeated character" mean?

Comment: Store the String characters in a List and then Match for successive repeatitions!

Comment: @DonBranson I think he means `oo` in `Google`, `pp` in `Apple` and so on.

Comment: "Consecutive repeated characters" might be a better way to phrase it.

Comment: @DavidConrad - yes, that's much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class replace
{

public static void main(String args[])
{
    String arr[]=new String[3];
    arr[0]="Google";
    arr[1]="Apple";
    arr[2]="Amazon";
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        int j;
        for(j=1;j<arr[i].length();j++)
        {
            if(arr[i].charAt(j) == arr[i].charAt(j-1))
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        if(j==arr[i].length())
                System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
}
}
```

Logic : Match the characters in a String with the previous character.

1. If you find string[i]==string[i-1]. Break the loop. Choose the next string.
2. If you have reached till the end of the string with no match having continuous repeated character, then print the string.

Comment: I am not able to do that as is showing up "Vote Up require 15 reputation"

Comment: what is the use of initializing j twice with value 1?

Comment: Corrected the code. @M.Sharma

Comment: You can just write `String[] names = { "Google", "Apple", "Amazon" };` and `for (String name : names)`. It would make the code a lot clearer without all the manual mucking around with arrays.