# How to check if a string contains three chars in consecutive order within a given string in any location?

Tags: java

I am working on an app integration with a website. Basically, I am a PHP developer but the android app is using Java and I am not very professional in it. I need to offer an option to change passwords via the app itself.

When the user enters a new password as a string, I want the app to
make sure that no substrings of length 3 from the old password are used in the new password. This check should be case insensitive.

Eg. If a user has the old password "Angel173MN", he/she cannot opt for any new password that contains any of the substrings: nge,l17,73M etc

Can anyone please guide me how to do it?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24435711/check-a-string-for-consecutive-repeated-characters

Comment: Yes, I tried some ideas found on this site but its complex for me. I am actually unable to compare the two Passwords and finding out the common three chars in the same order..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86780/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-another-string-in-a-case-insensitive-manner-in

Comment: Not that closely related, @coder-croc. That question is about recognizing double letters such as `oo` or `pp` in a string.

Comment: ' String num1 = "Java";
    String num2 = "Guava";
    int count = 0;
    List<String> charsChecked = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0;i < num1.length();i++){
        String charToCheck = num1.substring(i, i+1);

        if (!charsChecked.contains(charToCheck)) {
            count += StringUtils.countMatches(num2, charToCheck);
            charsChecked.add(charToCheck);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(count);'

Comment: @OleV.V. Yes, I agree. I thought it would be a good start for OP to find the solution. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    String oldPassword = "Angel173MN";
    String newPassword = "Tomato47nge";
    for (int i = 0; i < oldPassword.length() - 2; i++) {
        String sub = oldPassword.substring(i, i + 3);
        if (newPassword.contains(sub)) {
            System.out.println("Substring " + sub + " is part of both passwords");
        }
    }
```

Output:

> Substring nge is part of both passwords

As @coder-croc points out in a comment, you can break the loop at the first match since you don’t need to find more matches. Since I understood the string operations as the heart of your question, I will leave the logic to yourself.

The `String` class in Java has pretty good support for many string operations.

**Link:** [Documentation of `String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Comment: Thank you! that was simple and helpful.... Perhaps I am a little weak in formatting my question but your answer suffice

Comment: You can break the loop if you find the match! No need to iterate further. What do you think?

Comment: @coder-croc Good point. Edited.