# Python: How do I group recurring consecutive digits of only one type?

Tags: python, list, loops, logic, list-comprehension

I wrote this program to find certain consecutive recurring digits in a string and group them. The string only contains 0 and 1, and I want to shorten the recurring zeros by converting them to a number. Also, to avoid confusion I converted all the 1s to a letter. For example:

```
item = list("00011101110100010111010001110000")

for i in item:
    if i == "1":
        item[item.index(i)] = "n"
    if i == "0":
        index = item.index(i)
        zeros = 0
        for shft, _ in enumerate(item):
            try:
                if item[index+shft] == "1":
                    break
                if item[index+shft] == "0":
                    item.pop(index+shft)
                    zeros+=1
            except IndexError:
                pass
        item.insert(index, zeros)
        
print(item)
```

The expected output for this program I wrote is

```
[3, 'n', 'n', 'n', 1, 'n', 'n', 'n', 1, 'n', 3, 'n', 1, 'n', 'n', 'n', 1, 'n', 3, 'n', 4]
```

But the output I get is:

```
[2, 1, 'n', 'n', 'n', 1, 'n', 'n', 'n', 4, 'n', 1, 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 3, 'n', 1, 'n', 'n', 'n', 2, 1, 1]
```

I looked around for something of this kind which can group consecutive characters, and the closest thing I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24435711/check-a-string-for-consecutive-repeated-characters) Java example but I was having trouble implementing it in python.

I then tried this approach:

```
item = img[2]

zeros = 0
for idx, i in enumerate(item):
    if i == "0":
        zeros += 1
        item.pop(idx)
    elif i == "1":
        item[idx] = "n"
        if zeros != 0:
            item.insert(idx-1, zeros)
            zeros = 0
    elif i == "x":
        if zeros != 0:
            item.insert(idx-1, zeros)
            zeros = 0

print(item)
```

But the output was:

```
['0', 2, '1', 'n', 'n', 1, '1', 'n', 'n', '1', '0', '1', 4, '1', 'n', 'n', '1', '0', 3, '1', 'n', 'n', '0', 2, '0', 'x']
```

Could anyone please show me a better and faster approach than this and show me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: why do you want to output in the same `item` object/variable?

Comment: @VivekSable I only want to group the zeros, outputting to the same `item` list is not a requirement but I also didn't do it for any particular reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` for grouping consecutive items of the same key. Since you really only want to group 0s while leaving 1s separate items in this case, a trick I'd use is to use a key function that returns `False` for 0s and an incremental number for 1s so that 1s would not be grouped together as their keys are always unique. You can use `itertools.count` to generate such incremental numbers:

```
from itertools import groupby, count

item = '00011101110100010111010001110000'

c = count(1)
print([
    'n' if k else sum(1 for _ in g)
    for k, g in groupby(item, lambda i: i == '1' and next(c))
])
```

This outputs:

```
[3, 'n', 'n', 'n', 1, 'n', 'n', 'n', 1, 'n', 3, 'n', 1, 'n', 'n', 'n', 1, 'n', 3, 'n', 'n', 'n', 4]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) with a nested for-loop which decides whether to use the number of zeros or to repeat the ones:

```py
>>> import itertools as it
>>> item = '00011101110100010111010001110000'
>>> [x for k, g in it.groupby(item) for x in (('n' for _ in g) if k == '1' else [sum(1 for _ in g)])]
[3, 'n', 'n', 'n', 1, 'n', 'n', 'n', 1, 'n', 3, 'n', 1, 'n', 'n', 'n', 1, 'n', 3, 'n', 'n', 'n', 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

why do you want to output in the same item object/variable?

It is simple way -

```
item = list("00011101110100010111010001110000")
output = []
count_zeros = 0 
for  i in item:
    if i == "1":
        if count_zeros != 0:
            output.append(count_zeros)
        output.append("n")
        # Set count of zero to 0
        count_zeros = 0
    elif i == "0":
        count_zeros = count_zeros + 1
    else:
        print("This characher is not handled {}".format(i))


 print(output)
```